# Validation is failing when params are properly submitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 3.2
date_validator gem v 0.9.0
```

In my invoices_controller.rb, I have:

```
def submit_for_payment
  if params.has_key?("confirm_manual_processing")
     if !params[:manual_reference].empty? && !params[:manually_paid_at].empty?
      @records = Invoice.document_manual_payments_to_service_providers params
    else
      flash[:error] = "Reference Number Date Paid Both Required"
    end
  else
    if !params[:manual_reference].empty? || !params[:manually_paid_at].empty?
      flash[:error] = "Reference Number Date Paid Both Required AND you must confirm by checking the manual payment box"
    else
      @records = Invoice.pay_invoices_to_service_providers params[:invoices]
    end
  end
  redirect_to [ params[:redirect_path] || :needed_to_be_paid, :admin, :invoices ]
end
```

and in my invoices.rb, I have:

```
attr_accessible :manual_reference, :confirm_manual_processing, :manually_paid_at

validates :manually_paid_at, date: true
validates :manual_reference, length: { minimum: 6 }
```

But, when submitting the form, I am getting the following error:

```
Validation failed: Manually paid at is not a date, Manual reference is too short (minimum is 6 characters
Rails.root: /home/app

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/models/invoice.rb:159:in `block in document_manual_payments_to_service_providers'
app/models/invoice.rb:155:in `each'
app/models/invoice.rb:155:in `document_manual_payments_to_service_providers'
app/controllers/admin/invoices_controller.rb:161:in `submit_for_payment'
app/middleware/catch_json_parse_errors.rb:8:in `call'

Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"=>"5De4XkSwxuu4xLPqgwtHmpoXQ1yBSDGTXDesAZeBmdg=",
  "invoices"=>["1535114522_188841_invoice"],
  "manually_paid_at"=>"01/27/2019",
  "manual_reference"=>"1234567",
  "confirm_manual_processing"=>"1",
  "commit"=>"Submit For Payment"}
```

As you can see from the parameters, I am submitting a valid date and a valid length reference.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to permit the parameters if you want to mass assign them https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

Comment: This is Rails 3.2, not Rails 4.0+. The way it's handled in Rails 3.2, is through attr_accessible, which I have

Comment: sorry, I missed that. What do you see if you inspect the invoice before it's being saved? Because the date could give some problem depending on it's format, but the `manual_reference` shouldn't give you any error, try to inspect what's happening inside that `document_manual_payments_to_service_providers` with params and the new invoice (use something like pry-rails to stop execution inside the method so you can play with everything)

Answer (score 0):

i saw your error in param submition, that is:
`"manually_paid_at"=>"01/27/2019"`

So this is not a `Date` object, this is only `String` object, you must convert it to `Date` object.

You can use `to_date` to convert it to `Date` object

Comment: That did not solve the problem. I am getting the same error. Here's what I added to the controller action: params[:manually_paid_at] = params[:manually_paid_at].to_date

Answer (score 0):

- It looks like `manually_paid_at` is an invalid date you can use
  something like below to parse the datetime correctly before sending
  it to model

  `DateTime.strptime("01/27/2019", "%m/%d/%y")` => `Mon, 27 Jan 2020 00:00:00 +0000`
- For Manual reference is too short (minimum is 6 characters) I am not
  sure why model validation is adding that error because `"1234567"` is valid.. my guess is that param's value is not getting sent to the model as `"1234567"` may be check your code if that param value is getting modified somewhere you can also do something like below to see the value of the `manual_reference` in error message:

  `validates :manual_reference, length: { minimum: 6, message: "%{value} is invalid"}`